# Query function in Google Sheets isn't pulling rows after a certain date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet document with 2 tabs: 1 for raw data and the other tab uses a Query function to search for entered criteria. The function is not pulling any rows after the 11/9/2022 date.

[image: snippet]

In other words, if I type "Beacon light is Inop", I get the 11/9/2002 row in the results. But if I type "radar alt inop", nothing shows up.

What I've tried: making sure all entries in column B are text.

Here is the URL's address for those who want to tweak or try their hand:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17HIljpouuSN9maog8iA2U6hC9pkIgcQ1Q3QZpqv9XSo/edit?pli=1#gid=168025446

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=QUERY(RawData!A2:H, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G WHERE 1=1 "&
 IF(C1="",, " and H = '"&C1&"'")&
 IF(C2="",, " and A = '"&C2&"'"), 0)
```

[image]

correct output based on your dataset is one single row:

[image]

Comment: can you try typing "radar alt inop" (or any string dated on or after 11/10/22) in your sheet? I'm still getting a #N/A result, thanks!

Comment: "Left hand engine oil low" is a very common entry. When I type that phrase into the search box, all results are listed up to and including those dated 11/09, but nothing after, even though that phrase does exists after 11/09. Thanks!

Comment: @Jaron you are filtering/querying based on A and H column not C where the date is. e.g. it has nothing to do with date at all

Comment: Thank you! I originally set this system up using a REGEXEXTRACT formula so that users could enter a keyword without having to deal with wildcards, but have since changed the query using the CONTAIN condition. (Still find it odd that the old system worked for about 20000 rows. Guessing it's a google/formula glitch.) Thanks again!